# Integrating application with default in android

Tags: android

I am currently writing an application which performs a search operation requested by the server at a pre-defined server location. Now , i need to integrate this application into the default Search that is provided on the Android Device i.e.. it should appear as an option for the user to perform his search ... like there are options to search the web , android market etc.. So , i should have my app also besides this ...

I am in a fix as to how to do this. Any suggestions, help of any kind , links to tutorials , articles are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in need of Suggestion Provider, you can explore this and if i remember correctly, the user needs to explicitly add your app to the search list. (It doesn't happen automatically)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.html